# ConcurrentDictionary is not thread-safe in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using a concurrentDictionary instance:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentResource> concurrentResources;
```

, where:

```
private class ConcurrentResource
{
     private int counter;
     private FlexLucene.Index.IndexWriter writer;
}
```

I only want to store a counter for getting how many threads are using the `IndexWriter`.

```
private FlexLucene.Index.IndexWriter toggleIndexWriter(System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    IndexEngine.ConcurrentResource concurrentResource = this.concurrentResources.AddOrUpdate(
        directory.FullName,
        (directoryPath) =>
        {
            ********************************
            FlexLucene.Index.IndexWriter writer = this.createIndexWriter(directoryPath);   
            return new IndexEngine.ConcurrentResource(writer);
            ********************************
        },
        (directoryPath, internalConcurrentResource) =>
        {
            if (!internalConcurrentResource.Writer.IsOpen())
                internalConcurrentResource.Writer = this.createIndexWriter(directoryPath);

            internalConcurrentResource.Counter += 1;
            return internalConcurrentResource;
        }
    );

    return concurrentResource.Writer;
}
```

It baffles me that I'm using two threads, and debugging I've realized both threads are performing the lines marked as `************************`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind to provide a working chunk of code to test?

Comment: It's really impossible. There are a lot of code.

Comment: As remarks tells you: [If you call AddOrUpdate simultaneously on different threads, addValueFactory may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675(v=vs.110).aspx)